# What are the grounds for close in age exceptions in the Netherlands?

Tags: rape, netherlands

The age of consent in the Netherlands is 16 but

> Netherlands statutory rape law is violated when an individual has consensual sexual contact with a person under age 16 out of wedlock. Close in age exemptions, at the discretion of the prosecution, exist for minors close in age in a relationship within "social-ethical norms" (outside of these norms could be a group sex or even an unequal relationship, meaning that the offender was not in love with the victim)

How are things like "offender was not in love with the victim" calculated ? Is it even possible to calculate something like that?

Comment: out of wedlock?? does the netherlands allow child marriage??